# Same ISP problems to load balancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, 3g, adsl

I have TP-Link TL-R470T+ Load balancer. I have purchased it to combine my three internet connections. (ADSL, 3G Dongle, 3G Dongle)
3G dongles have same network (ISP).
I have connected 3G dongles > router > Load balancer and ADSL though the router > Load balancer.
I'm able to combine ADSL and **one** 3G dongle but unable to combine all 3 or **two** Dongles.
I think it is because 3G dongles have the **same ISP**.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: On routers you have routing protocols RIP for example to determine the best route. I saw the specs for your model and I did not saw any roiting protocols. Second to be able to use routing protocols your ISP have to talk back to you if not is worthless. Since your router is not using not using any protocol how will we now how routing is perform what what route have priorities ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The Load Balancer doesn't care and can't know that they are the same ISP.

Comment: No, I don't. But in this context OP wants the router to load balance the internet connections as a client, not a provider. So no need for the router to _talk_ to the ISP

Comment: Routers route connections from 1 network to another network or networks. They use routing protocols to determine the correct route either fastest, shorter etc depending on the need and protocol. If you have 2 IP addresses from the same ISP and network **200.1.1.X** AND **200.1.1.Y** they are from the same network so no need to route them (that's how routers work). So how you now that the balancer does not care either you work in TP-Link (and develop the algorithm for this device) or you don't know how routers works.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insight. From the router's perspective you can have 2 interfaces on the same network with the same gateway and still have 2 0.0.0.0/0 valid routes to balance traffic from the internal network to the outside. Makes absolutely no difference for the SOHO router/LB that is discussed on the original post. Does this add to the original question? Have a good day.